# Equivalent to Google Play Games Service / iOS Game Center for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, multiplayer

I am creating a cross platform app, that supports real time multiplayer gaming.
In iOS, I can use Game Center, to create a peer to peer real time match. Likewise, I can use Google Play Game services for  both iOS and Android.

But I couldn't find any documentation for doing the equivalent for Windows Phone 8 ? I read somewhere about using Xbox Live, but couldn't find the documentation on how to do this for a Windows Phone 8 App.

Is it just not possible ? Is there a way to port Google Play Game Services to Windows Phone 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiplayer support I guess you will need to create xbox game.Microsoft has its own play service.For more details refer this link http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Microsoft-Launches-Play-Service,20510.html .Also please take a look at appwarp for multi player gaming in widnwos phone 8 http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/windows-game-developers-home/